# Netbeans GUI and non-static method

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, non-static

I'm trying to make an app where I have 3 classes. A Controlller (Main Class), SerialHandler and MainWindow which is a JFrame Form created with the NetBeans Gui Builder.

```
public class Controller {
    SerialHandler serialHandler;
    MainWindow mainWindow;
    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Controller controller = new Controller();
        controller.initializeSystem(controller);
    }
    public void initializeSystem(Controller _controller){
        mainWindow = new MainWindow(_controller);
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void anotherMethod(){
        mainWindow.setMyLabelText("Hello");
    }
}
```

So the problem is that if I doit like that and an event from the SerialHandler class calls anotherMethod(), the setMyLabelText method doesn't work but if I called it from the initializeSystem(); it works.

Now if I declare the mainwindow inside the main then the mainWindow instance is not visible from the anotherMethod().

If I declare the mainWindow object outside the main and try to use its method from main context I can't because the mainWindow object have been declared outside the non-static context.

Could anyone help me or at least point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to pass references in to the object that needs to use them. This can be done with a constructor parameter or a `setXXX(...)` "setter" method.

Comment: Your code will not compile public anotherMethod() { is invalid java syntax

Comment: The problem is that how do I pass the mainWindow object to the class where I created? My method is in the Controller class but I create my mainWindow inside this class... so what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a design inconsistency with your code:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
       Controller controller = new Controller();
       controller.initializeSystem(controller);
   }
   public void initializeSystem(){
       mainWindow = new MainWindow(_controller);
       mainWindow.setVisible(true);
   }
```

You are creating the controller that you are passing as an argument to its `initializeSystem` which is superfluous as you could just use `this` inside `initializeSystem`.

You should do this instead:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
       Controller controller = new Controller();
       controller.initializeSystem();
   }
   public void initializeSystem(Controller _controller){
       mainWindow = new MainWindow(this);
       mainWindow.setVisible(true);
   }
```

The second inconsistency is the method `anotherMethod` which accesses your UI and updates stuff in it. You should leave that to the controller instead. Something like this:

```
public class Controller {
     //...

     public void updateUIText(String text){
           SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                mainWindow.setMyLabelText("Hello");
              }
           });
     }
}
```

Now, the `SerialHandler` can update the UI via the Controller when it needs to. All what you have to do is to pass in the `Controller` reference to the `SerialHandler`

**EDIT** Note that I used the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to update the UI, this will ensure the `Controller` will correctly update the UI even in multithreaded scenarios which I assume is your case

Comment: Now that's what I call Help. I'm not use to the run() but I'll try it out :). Thanks. Any other ideas on this would be appreciated.

Comment: @Twistx77 Glad to help :) The `run()` method updates your UI from the UI thread also called EDT.